# R: Assignments to list elements slower with class attribute

Tags: r, performance, list, oop

I did some profiling in the context of S3 and S4 classes and observed the following:

A simple value assignment to an element of S3 objects is about 2-3 times slower compared to the same operation on the corresponding plain lists.

From my point of view the S3 class is a list with an additional attribute and the element is just a numeric. So, which mechanisms consume the additional time?

```
value <- 1 
obj_list <- list( a = 0 )
obj_s3 <- structure( obj_list, class = "myclass" )

system.time( 
  replicate( 100000, obj_list$a <- value)
) # ~180 ms

system.time( 
  replicate( 100000, obj_s3$a <- value)
) # ~420 ms
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As soon as you add a class to your R variable you make it an object subject to S3 dispatch.  Since `$<-` acts like an S3 generic, `$<-` will attempt to dispatch based on the class of your object.  If you look at the C code for `$<-`, you can see:

```
/* From src/main/subassign.c

   $<-(x, elt, val)
*/
SEXP attribute_hidden do_subassign3(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
  // ... code omitted  
  if(DispatchOrEval(call, op, "$<-", args, env, &ans, 0, 0))
      return(ans);
  // ... code omitted  
}
```

`DispatchOrEval` will only kick off the S3 dispatch if the argument is an object (i.e. has a class or is an S4 object).  Note that even for objects without methods S3 dispatch has overhead because the default method must still be found.  This is a little clearer if we look at non-primitive S3 generics like `mean` where it becomes obvious that the dispatch process is:

```
> mean
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x000000000fd151c0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Which shows that the following is really happening when you call `mean` on an object without a method:

```
mean(obj) => UseMethod() => find method => mean.default(obj)
```

The extra call and the process of looking up the matching method adds the overhead you are observing.  This isn't obvious for stuff like `$<-` or `sum` since all that stuff is being done via C code in `DispatchOrEval`.

To illustrate:

```
> obj <- structure(1:10, class="wookkawooka")
> var <- 1:10
> 
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(mean(obj), mean(var), mean.default(obj))
Unit: microseconds
              expr    min     lq     mean median      uq    max neval
         mean(obj) 12.069 13.166 16.46442 13.166 13.7145 95.813   100
         mean(var)  8.046  8.777  9.51974  8.778  9.1430 31.084   100
 mean.default(obj)  6.217  7.314  9.17234  7.680  8.0460 84.111   100
```

Note the difference does not appear as marked here because the `mean.default` function itself has more overhead than primitives like `$<-` so the dispatch time is a lesser proportion of total time.  Also, note that for non-objects the dispatch still happens (unlike with primitives), except that the decision to use the default method can be made much faster.  This is why `mean(var)` is a little slower than `mean.default(obj)` but faster than `mean(obj)`.

Here is a **[a blog post on S3/S4 dispatch performance](http://www.brodieg.com/?p=26)** that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Correct answer, but wrong function. It's `$<-` not `$` in the example. Defining ``$<-.myclass` <- function(...) print("hello")` makes it obvious.

Comment: That blog post you linked to is quite interesting!